# Is it possible to see the precise steps that the Fed uses to make its decisions?

Tags: federal-reserve

The current economic in the US is very complex and uncertain. Is it possible to see the precise steps that the Fed uses to make its decisions? Why did they choose a rate of that amount and not another amount?

Comment: Reading FOMC minutes (https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm) might help. Doubt if they'll outline precise steps on their minds though.

Comment: Remember that this is a decision by a committee.  The points that they consider are published, but the decision is simply what a majority of individuals decided personally after considering those points